Apt minimal of list packages and dependencies (tree)
Is there a tool that takes the currently installed apt/deb/snap packages and produces a list of the minimum set of packages to install to get the entire list via all the dependencies?
E.g. If I run apt list --installed | cut -f1 -d/ I get all 2000+ pkgs on my laptop, but installing a small subset should be enough to get all of them.
It seems like apt-rdepends and a bit of scripting should be able to produce this. In fact this might make a good interview question...

You should be able to reproduce a freshly-installed system with merely the ubuntu-desktop metapackage.
